# How to enter the escape characters for telnet programmatically?

Tags: python, ssh, escaping, telnet, paramiko

I'm using paramiko to ssh into a remote machine, this much seems to be working fine so far

`client.connect(hostname, port=ssh_port, username=username, key_filename=key_fname, password=password)`

Now from the remote machine I need to go deeper, and using

`stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('telnet localhost %d'%port)`

seems to give me the right handles to start talking using `stdin.write`

My problem is that when I'm done, I don't know how to quit telnet correctly.  If I do it manually, I can go into the telnet and I see:  `Escape character is '^]'.`  I can use `Ctrl+]` on the keyboard, and a little menu pops up saying

```
Console escape. Commands are:

 l  go to line mode
 c  go to character mode
 z  suspend telnet
 e  exit telnet
```

and then I'm able to quit by pressing 'e' (it quits immediately with no 'enter' key necessary)

But when I try to do this in my script, by `stdin.write('^]e')`, `stdin.write('\^]e')`, `stdin.write('\c]e')`, `stdin.write('\M-\C-]e')`, etc.. all the time I just see in `stdout.read()` that my script has entered those characters literally.  Putting a little `time.sleep(0.1)` inbetween the `]` and `e` does not seem to help.

How can I enter that escape sequence programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I've worked it out.

The short answer: `'\x1d'`

That's the escape sequence to bring up the little menu.  I found this via `curses` module:

```
from curses.ascii import ctrl
print ctrl(']')
```